# Correct way to implement css hover and focus on icon

Tags: html, css, icons

I want to add background color and make the size bigger of my icon when its hovered but what is the correct way to implement a:hover on this CSS code?

```
li a i.menu-icon {
        color: #f3698a;
        float: left;
        width: 33px;
        font-size: 12px
    }
```

Comment: You can use `li a:hover i.menu-icon {  }`.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul That looks like the correct way to do this, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:
(You can change the background color to what you want, I put #000 for demonstration only, also you can change the width value To what you need)

```
li a i.menu-icon:hover {
            Background-color:#000;
            color: #fff;
            width: 50px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
```

Comment: I tried using this method but in my case, the CSS didn't work when I added ':hover' at the end.

Comment: Then try putting the :hover after the a tag

Comment: yes, my issue has been solved after putting :hover after 'a' tag as Debsmita Paul explained. Thank you thou.